# Terminate resource group automatically based on a time window

Tags: azure

I'm not sure if it's an off topic for SO but I really need help here. Now in my project we are running load test on weekly basic and we are taking the advantage of ARM and azure CLI for making it fully automated test framework, starting from vm spinning to report gen.

But after the test, for now we are terminating the resource group manually and we have few though to make it automatic e.g by running a cron job. So just I'm curious if there is a better approach to do a graceful termination/destroy(not stop) automatically using azure cli based on a time window.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such a way, but if everything is automated, you can run `az group delete xxx` at the end of your script\automation routine.

On top of that, take a look at [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/). Its a new service that can create actions in response to events.

Comment: The automated framework will spin necessary resource and start the grinder process and the test will run in background asynchronously based on a time window.

Comment: well, make the test run that command, or issue a webhook with the test to delete the resource group, make az cli sleep for certain period of time if you know it upfront. there is no way az cli knows how long your test will take.

Comment: Yes, recently I came across event grid :)